# div width 100% without overflowing to next line

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="transport">
    <div id="design_header">

    </div>
    <div id="design_image">
    </div>
    <div id="design_right_content">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries<br />
        <ul id="design_list">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>
                two</li>
            <li>
                three</li>
            <li>
                four</li>
        </ul>

   </div>
</div>

#design_right_content{
border: 1px solid;
float: left;
width: 400px;
overflow:hidden;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #E1DFD9;
display: inline;
 }
#transport{
border: 1px solid;
float: right;
width: 800px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #E1DFD9;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#design_header{
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #006A4D;
height: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
clear:both;
float:left;
}
#design_image{
border: 1px solid;
float: left;
width: 300px;
min-height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline;
background-color: orange;
}
```

For the above is there a way to have the div design_right_content have width:100% without it getting carried over to the next line?

Comment: It also depends on what you put inside the div. If it goes over the div, by width, it'll go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (slightly amusingly) do this by simply removing a bunch of properties.

Change `#design_right_content` to this:

```
#design_right_content {
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #E1DFD9;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TqHkp/

This has the advantage that you don't need to specify any `width` on `#design_right_content`.

Which is a major improvement if you wanted to make this fluid width: http://jsfiddle.net/TqHkp/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your #design_right_content to this:

```
#design_right_content{
     ...
     width: 360px;
     ...
 }
```

The padding adds to the width of an element therefore bumping it down

Comment: I intend to not worry about the width of the #design_right_content by just putting it as 100%